# Power BI - grouped sum by week

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

i´m trying to build a new table with a weekly sum but by a col "canal" so in the "total_semana" column you can see the sum of the week for each "canal", then calculate the weekly share by "canal".

i tried adding a new col called "wnum" for the week number and sum by it, but no success in the "total_semana" col so far.

[Example data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mxKP.png)

the folowing table show the expected result, red, sum by week, blue its share.

[expected table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hqqs.png)

Thank you  all in advance.

Comment: Could you show your expected output, cannot really understand the meaning of weekly share by "canal"

Comment: thks Kin! i add an expected output, the blue its a natural division of "suma_vta" by "total_semana" for each "canal", the red blocks its sum by week for all "canal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your weekly total:

```
total_semana =
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( week_sum[suma_vta] ) , 
    ALLEXCEPT ( week_sum , week_sum[wnum] , week_sum[Año] )
)
```

For your % of weekly total:

```
participacion_semanal =
DIVIDE ( 
    week_sum[suma_vta] ,
    week_sum[total_semana]
)
```

Comment: thks Marcus! the allexcept function works like a charm!